# Instantiate object on page load, maintain value and pass to partial view on AJAX load?

Tags: razor-pages

How to do this in Razor pages?

On page load I want to load a list of Cars into an object that I can later access when I load a partialview via an AJAX call.

When I run the code below (after I click the 'Load' button) the values of 'Cars' in OnGetCarPartial is null...

How do I maintain the value of 'Cars' between initial content page load and the subsequent AJAX call?

(Note the reason I want to do this, is that eventually I want  _carService.ReadAll to run asynchronously in a thread on page load, updating the 'Cars' list every second, so whenever I load the partialview, I get the latest 'Cars' list without having to call _carService.ReadAll().)

**PageModel:**

```
namespace ApiTest.Pages.Cars
{
    public class AjaxPartialModel : PageModel
    {
        private ICarService _carService;
        public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public AjaxPartialModel(ICarService carService)
        {
            _carService = carService;
            
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
           if (Cars == null)
           {
                Cars = _carService.ReadAll();
            }
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnGetCarPartial()
        {
            return Partial("_CarPartial", Cars);
        }
    }
}
```

**Content page AJAX**

```
@page
@model AjaxPartialModel

<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">Load</button></p>
<div id="grid"></div>

@section scripts{
    <script>     
        $(function () {
            $('#load').on('click', function () {
                $('#grid').load('/Cars/Index?handler=CarPartial');
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: A new `PageModel` instance is created for each request. If you want the car list to be saved and reused you need to use cache: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos thanks - how can I run a thread in the background that persists between requests? I want to start thread on page load & it run until session ends. Is it possible with Razor pages or am I using wrong tech...

Comment: Basically you need to create a background task that periodically calls `_carService.ReadAll()` and updates the cache. Then in the `PageModel` you return the list from cache instead of calling `_carService.ReadAll()`. https://medium.com/medialesson/run-and-manage-periodic-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core-6-with-c-578a31f4b7a3